# Trying to do a conditional double sorting by distance. One between the rows themselves and second to a main coordinate

Tags: sql

I want to query all coordinates around a location, but if the coordinates less than 50 m away from each other sort those ones by rating if not sort them by distance.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM public."MY_TABLE" AS t1
) AS TB 
WHERE ST_Intersects(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(
        -0.102769, 51.506590,
        -0.044822, 51.542643,
        4326
    ),
    TB.coordinates::geometry
)
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN ST_Distance(Tb.coordinates::geography, Tb.coordinates::geography) < 50 THEN TB.rating
        ELSE ST_Distance(TB.coordinates::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.073796, 51.524617), 4326))
    END;
```

I have used an order by CASE but this seems to compare the table against itself and the same row. Row1 vs row1 as opposed to row1vs row2.

update:(solved) I am using a cluster to group nearby locations by the same id. Then select those clustered to average their distance. So, when sorted by distance and rating the ones that are nearby are sorted together.

```
WITH clusters AS (
                  SELECT *, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(coordinates::geometry, eps := 0.00045, minpoints := 2) OVER () AS cluster_id
                  FROM public."MY_TABLE"
                  WHERE ST_DWithin(coordinates::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.073796, 51.524617), 4326), 2000.000000)
                  ), 
                  centroids AS (
                        SELECT cluster_id,
                                   ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(coordinates::geometry)) AS cluster_centroid
                        FROM clusters
                        WHERE cluster_id IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY cluster_id
                )
                SELECT clusters.id, clusters.name, clusters.website, clusters.coordinates, clusters.description, clusters.rating
                FROM clusters
                LEFT JOIN centroids 
                ON clusters.cluster_id = centroids.cluster_id
                ORDER BY 
                        CASE 
                                WHEN clusters.cluster_id IS NULL THEN ST_Distance(clusters.coordinates::geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.073796, 51.524617), 4326))
                                ELSE ST_Distance(centroids.cluster_centroid::geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.073796, 51.524617), 4326))
                        END,
                        rating
```

Comment: Please tag your post correctly.

Comment: Did adding the clusters solve the problem?  If so, it should be is an answer, not an edit.  If not, what is the point of doing it, or telling us about it?

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags.